# Is there an equivalent to SAS sas7bdat table files in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sas

Is there a Python equivalent to reading and writing tabular files such as SAS sas7bdat files?

My team is moving away from SAS and we'd like to replicate the SAS process in Python with our methodology as follows:

1) Pull data from various sources i.e. Excel, CSV, DBs etc.

2) Update our Data Warehouse with the new information and export this data as a Python table file (to be used next)

3) Rather than pulling data from our warehouse (super slow) we'd like to read in those Python table files and then do some data matching on a bigger set of data.

We're trying to avoid using the sas7bdat altogether (SASPy) files since we won't have SAS for much longer

Any advice, insights is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like Pandas would be worth a look. (https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: Basically sas7bdat is some custom header with an array of structs appended. When wanting to build something similar you could use python standard file io functions and the struct module.

Comment: #3 is really where SAS outdoes other languages (as someone moving away from SAS as well). Connecting to the DB and allowing work to occur on the server instead of desktop is a better use of resources.

Comment: Thanks all, will start investigating!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike SAS, Python doesn't have a native data format. However, there are modules that  implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object. Consider using HDF5 format to save and read files (https://www.h5py.org/). Another possibility is Pickle (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Yeah I've recently started working with pickle files! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Parquet](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html) is also worth considering.